# Azure Custom Auth with Node.js Backend

Tags: node.js, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to login clients using their email and password through Auth0 with a Node.js backend on the Azure app service and a Xamarin.Forms client. The problem is that I can't create a custom authentication on Node.js since [the tutorial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/#using-azure-active-directory-b2c) I was following used a .NET backend. I also followed this [tutorial](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/) for Node.js backend both by the awesome Adrian Hall, but it seems to override the already exisiting Facebook login system, and I can't find enough material on that problem. Is there any other tutorial on doing that or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-users

Comment: I want custom authentication not only through Facebook

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have tried to add custom route but I cannot access the azureMobile context into.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong.  You can use Auth0 with no problems - Auth0 will be used for all the providers, and their client SDKs will allow you to choose Facebook, Google, Username/Password or anything else you need.

The mechanism for the process is as documented - I think you just need to re-read the blog post and understand the transaction - you use the Auth0 libraries to get the Auth0 token, then submit your Auth0 token to your custom login API (/.auth/login/custom) to mint an App Service token that is used by the Azure Mobile Apps client SDK.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. What I intended by Facebook login was logging in through Facebook's independent SDK and configuring Azure with Facebook not Auth0. What I want is to have multiple ways of logging in other that Auth0. In .NET, it was clear that I should make a controller with a certain route like (.auth/login/auth0) and map that route. I don't understand how to make that in Node.js, is it the same just in another language?

Comment: Sort of.  You will write a piece of middleware that then gets hooked into the ExpressJS route.  I'd probably rethink what I want out of the login flow - Auth0 is designed to do everything for you, and the experience for your users will be a little disjoint if you do what you propose.

Comment: Okay. Thanks very much for your time.